# Reduce one from absolute value?

Tags: c#, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have an integer that needs its absolute value to be reduced by one.

Is there a shorter way than this:

```
if(number > 0) number--; else if (number < 0) number++;
```

Comment: what language? /15char

Comment: I'm using C# although the code in question concludes I'm talking about a C-family language.

Comment: `number - (number > 0) + (number < 0)`

Comment: @peinearydevelopment, yeah, but then I want to retain the original negative/positive value.

Comment: @Nemo could be great if it wouldn't be C#... Nice catch anyway.

Comment: now you have some *shorter* versions and the one you gave is indeed the most readable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even shorter:

```
number -= Math.Sign(number);
```

[`Math.Sign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sign.aspx) returns `-1`, `0`, or `1` depending on the sign of the specified value.

**Extension Method**

Since you say you face this situation a lot it might be beneficial to make this an extension method to better express your intent:

```
public static int ReduceFromAbsoluteValue(this int number, int reduceValue)
{
    return number - Math.Sign(number) * reduceValue;
}

4.ReduceFromAbsoluteValue(1);  // 3
-4.ReduceFromAbsoluteValue(1); // -3
0.ReduceFromAbsoluteValue(1);  // 0
```

Alternatively name this `AddToAbsoluteValue` and change it to add the value.

Comment: that's the one! In my particular project, I face this situation a lot. Great solution!

Answer (score 2):

Slightly shorter:

`number += number > 0 ? -1 : 1;`

If all you need is the absolute value:

`Math.Abs(number) - 1`

Comment: Oops, sorry forgot the ternary. But is there a math hack, just for the sake of the nerdness.

Comment: For anyyone who cares, this is different than the original code for `number == 0`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Right. I wrapped @knrz's line in an `if(number == 0)` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Hack time!

```
return number - (number >> 31) + (-number >> 31);
```

`x >> 31` will be -1 if `x < 0`, 0 otherwise. So if `number < 0` it will subtract -1 (add 1). If `number > 0` then `-number < 0` and it adds -1 if `number > 0`. Both things are zero when `number == 0` so it leaves that alone.

Answer (score 0):

(Math.Abs(number) - 1)*Math.Sign(number)